# Merge one feature branch with the other, with the option of reverting without commit history for the merge

Tags: git, frontend

I am working a feature , a checkout page , now the workflow that i have adopted is like so:

2 developers ( 2 branches , one for frontend and one for backend ), named `feature-checkout-frontend` and `feature-checkout-backend`. Now for for frontend i need say 4-5 API's in total , also one the developer is done working on say one API and i integrated into my `feature-checkout-frontend` branch , so i can start working on my stuff, i may usually request changes to the API.

As you can see , i have to continually merge the backend changes into my `feature-checkout-frontend` branch, now how do i keep my `feature-checkout-frontend` branch clean I.E.

1. I would like to revert back the backend changes at anytime (`revert` can be used , but i would prefer not to.)
2. I should be able to continually integarte the backend changes into my branch everytime the backend dev is done with his API work.

So the workflow would be something like this.

- Backend dev creates API and pushs to `feature-checkout-backend`
- I merge `feature-checkout-backend` into `feature-checkout-frontend`
- I request some changes for the API
- Backend dev makes the changes.
- **(This is where things get interesting)** , i would like to run a command here where the previous merge of backend change just disappear.
- After i complete above step, now i would merge the `feature-checkout-backend` into `feature-checkout-frontend`.

Any suggestions are welcome , and maybe my way is not the right way, so advice is welcome. To reiterate my point i need to continually merge `feature-checkout-backend` with `feature-checkout-frontend`. so whats the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In gitflow, the backend dev should merge to develop when the features are done. From there you should pull your changes. His/Her feature branch may not at all be available to you.
It looks like you're actually maintaining two develop branches disguised as fauture. Which is fine, but then you should name it like so and branch off from those with specific features.

> (This is where things get interesting) , i would like to run a command here where the previous merge of backend change just disappear.

Checkout the older commit and create a new branch.

---

*Btw: the correct way of doing the above is to just merge again. Not to undo them. Don't try to hide history. Who cares if you have a dozen merges back and forward in your "develop" branches, so what? When merged with master the feature branches be deleted anyway.*

Comment: so you're saying a 3rd branch is needed right ?, the way our workflow works is , during development we can't merge to develop. so i guess you're saying create a feature branch and then from that branch create `frontend` and `backend` branches that we work on independently. Am i right ?

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik Well, yes. Git is a tool, there are many opinions on how to use it. In general you keep track of history, you ask to remove history, which in the opposite of what git is for. You can only do this by going back and re-brancing. (if pushed) eg: feature-alex-frontend-attempt2. Or you can revert the changes of said merge in a new commit. Or just merge again, that is the best option I think.